# How do I update the text seen on a membership payment page when the autorenwal option is provided?

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions, auto-renew

Running on Drupal 7.69 and Civi 5.18.x.

We would like to update the text that gets displayed when the auto-renewal option is active for membership types. Is there a way of doing using the admin interface or does it have to be done with code?

Image of current text is below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the word replacement function to do so. It is described in the CiviCRM documentation [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/customizing-the-user-interface/#using-word-replacement-to-change-terminology).

Sometimes a text is composed of more than one string which means that you would have to do more that one word replacement.